# IF doesnt work when used with enabledelayedexpansion in batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, command-line

This batch file will kill all processes found by psList, except for those whitelisted. The final IF in the following code, that I need to kill the non-whitelisted processes, doesn't work and I don't know why. How come?

```
            @echo off

            REM cd to the dir where this .bat file is in.
            cd /d %0\.. 

            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
            REM If we don't do enabledelayedexpansion, the variables won't be able to hold values and will only store blanks. Also we need to show variables like this : !variable! instead of %variable%. http://superuser.com/questions/78496/variables-in-batch-file-not-being-set-when-inside-if

            :: Goal : Kill all processes except those whitelisted.

            for /f "skip=3 tokens=1" %%i in ('pslist -accepteula') do (

                rem Set a variable to indicate if we kill the task or not. Boolean.
                set bKill=1 

                :: Whitelist : 
                if "%%i"=="svchost" SET bKill=0
                if "%%i"=="explorer" SET bKill=0
                if "%%i"=="cmd" SET bKill=0
                if "%%i"=="tasklist" SET bKill=0
                if "%%i"=="searchui" SET bKill=0
                if "%%i"=="lsass" SET bKill=0
                if "%%i"=="dwm" SET bKill=0
                if "%%i"=="sihost" SET bKill=0 
                if "%%i"=="dllhost" SET bKill=0 

                echo.
                echo %%i
                echo bkill value is = !bKill!
                :: I cannot make the following line to work: 
                if "!bKill!"=="1" @echo It works.
                :: The following line is the line I really want to work in the end. To troubleshoot the "if" and keep it simple I've replaced what was after the IF by an echo (line above).
                rem if "!bKill!"=="1" pskill -accepteula -t  "%%i" 

                pause

            )
```

Comment: Don't use `::` for comments as it's technically a label. Use `rem` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set bKill=1 
           ^ Ending space included in value
```

As there is an space included, the test

```
if "!bKill!"=="1" @echo It works.
if      "1 "=="1" @echo It works
```

will never be evalueated to true.

Better use

```
set "bKill=1"
```

preventing the inclusion of unneeded spaces